# How to pack integers of arbitrary size to byte buffer in Python

Tags: python, binary-data

The other way is simple `int(byte_buffer.encode('hex'), 16 )`

But how do I convert that integer back to `byte_buffer`.

The length will be stored by prepending `struct.pack('>I', len(byte_buffer))` to the value.

In 2.7 there is `int.bit_length()` that would be a good start, but unfortunately I must be able to run this also on 2.6.

Comment: Solved this myself, but don't know how optimal my solution is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with.

```
def int2str(i):
    _bytes = list()
    while i > 0:
        n = i % 256
        _bytes.insert(0, n)
        i = i >> 8
    return ''.join(struct.pack('B', x) for x in _bytes)
```

Comment: Here you have the problem that the length of what comes out can vary. So maybe you want to fix that. Besides, `struct.pack('B', x)` is the same as `chr(x)`...